# Convert text file to json format python

Tags: json

I have a text file with data in following format.

{

"id":123

"value":2.5

"sentiment":"negative"

}

But when i try to do json operations in it, it shows error no module named 'load'.
How can i convert that text file to proper json format and do json operations. how can i extract sentiment  value in field.

Comment: also, shouldn't JSON have the values comma separated?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import json
with open("filename", 'r') as f:
    json.load(f)
```

Also change your json like this for it to be valid:

```
{

"id":123,

"value":2.5,

"sentiment":"negative"

}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but error message: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: @Sreetha I think it might be because your JSON is invalid. Look at the edit